# Address Book contacts in Skype

Tags: macos, skype, address-book

Why do some of my Address Book contacts show up in Skype, but not others? I would give more info but I haven't been able to find a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype only lists **contacts with actual phone numbers** in its address book.

See: [Can I call my Address Book contacts in Skype for Mac OS X?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10899/Can-I-call-my-Address-Book-contacts-in-Skype-for-Mac-OS-X?frompage=search&q=address%20book&fromSearchFirstPage=false)

> All Address Book contacts with a phone number will be displayed in your contact list.

Comment: Hmm. I guess the ones that are missing have international numbers. Pretty disappointing that Skype can't figure that out...

Comment: Skype shouldn't have problems with international numbers. I have [plenty of them](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7qrzq.png).

Answer (score 3):

It does appear to pick up any number that you enter into the telephone numbers section even if some are missing the international dialing code.  You can set the default dialing code in preferences.

Check that all the numbers that are missing are correctly entered into the telephone numbers section in the address book.  My wife for example had entered some of the numbers into the e-mail address field so they didn't show up in Skype.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the numbers ABOVE the one I wanted to call, and now the contact shows up fine in Skype.

One of the numbers AVOBE the one I wanted to call had commas in it, and some code I used with long distance calling cards.

So it seems the answer is "Skype doesn't show a contact based on it having at least ONE valid number, but expecting ALL of them being valid"

Once Skype finds an invalid number, it can't read the next. (SQL query getting corrupt because of the commas?)